# Does accepting duality lead only to nondual skillfull qualities?

Tags: nonduality, right-action

This question can seem contradictory but form my understanding ,duality is inherent in reality and accepting reality in all its dualities leads to more conscious actions. But if the person as a result acquires ONLY positive qualities then isn't this dual and not in accord with nature?

Buddhism lays emphasis that qualities like ,jealosy ,hate,pride and anger are unskillful and qualities like love,peace,contenmtent and compassion are. Don't we kill animals and plants to eat ,don't we fight in wars in self defense, these are negative but right actions to take and underlie negative qualities of brutality .

Can we cry consciously can we kill consciously ?

Comment: [This topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/28504/254) may be related -- it's about understanding or misunderstanding non-duality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a wonderful one. What should be defined and addressed in order to clear up your confusion is this:

What defines a “skillful” quality?

In classical Buddhism, something is skillful if it leads you closer to enlightenment. But why are experiences such as jealousy, pride, hate, and anger unskillful? All of these emotions *enhance and reinforce* a belief in duality. When you are jealous, **you** (someone separate) desire something **they** (someone separate) wants. Every unskillful experience arises because of a belief in separateness. It is only through observing first hand that the belief in duality is an illusion that we can be truly free.

It seems from your question, you believe that *actions* can be positive or negative. It is important to remember **positive and negative are born from desire.** No action or object is inherently “good” or “bad”. What makes something positive or negative is our own desires and orientation towards those experiences. Here are two examples to illustrate this.

The sky is blue. Most would say the sky being blue is neutral. If I wished more than anything in the world the sky was always orange, I would suffer most of the time, but find some peace during sunsets. If I desired the sky to be blue, it would bring me much joy most of the time, but I would suffer during sunsets.

All things are inherently neutral. Killing an animal for food is only a negative action if you don’t want to kill animals. If you are a vegan, you suffer while doing it. If you are a hunter, it brings you joy while doing it.

> Can we cry consciously can we kill consciously ?

This is exactly what enlightenment is. Right now, because you believe yourself to be a separate entity observing the world, you see many things that are not. Killing and crying are illusions. To someone who has not yet observed Nirvana, killing and crying are interpreted as painful actions that cause suffering. But when you see beyond the illusion, you will find that very same suffering doesn’t arise from killing and crying, but from the belief that there is someone present that is being harmed. Once you experience Nirvana first hand, it becomes clear that the only thing here is Nirvana. There is no you. There is no I. There is no killing. There is no crying. There is only peace.

I hope these words have been helpful to you on your path. I pray for nothing more than your liberation this lifetime.

Comment: You definitely cleared my confusion regarding skillful qualities.Very well put Nagasena :)